# Como Subir Aquivos de Planilha No Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, apex, workflow

Olá, tenho uma demanda para ser cumprida logo e estou com  bastante dificuldade, subir no Apex Oracle, varias versões de planilhas, e que essas planilhas possam ser acessadas dentro do próprio aplicativo e adicionada uma coluna nova, e se possivel, fazer o download dessas planilhas para a maquina local.